# How to handle MMddyyyy date format in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, date-format, date-conversion

I am getting the date in following string formats from third party vendor API:

```
MM/dd/yyyy
yyyy/MM/dd
yyyyMMdd
yyyy-MM-dd
MMddyyyy
```

So some of the records have date of birth in `yyyy-MM-dd` and some of the records have DOB in other format.
Except format `MMddyyyy`, all the formats are converted to `yyyy-MM-dd` using SQL Convert/Cast function.

How do I convert `MMddyyyy` it to `yyyy-MM-dd`?

I am trying below statement in SQL Server 2019 but its not working:

```
DECLARE @dt varchar(8)= '02022020';
SELECT CAST(@dt as date) s1;

Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 20
Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.
```

Is there any way I can handle this scenario in SQL Server?

Be informed: I am trying to implement below ADF code using SQL stored procedure.

```
coalesce(toDate(DOB,'MM/dd/yyyy')
        ,toDate(DOB,'yyyy/MM/dd')
        ,toDate(DOB,'yyyyMMdd')
        ,toDate(DOB,'MMddyyyy')
        ,toDate(DOB,'yyyy-MM-dd'))
```

Comment: Have a look at [`CONVERT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) and it's many style codes.

Comment: Unfortunately this format is not mentioned in [Convert](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: No, you''ll need to put it into the one it does support with a small amount of string manipulation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no style code for `MMddyyyy` as far as I am aware, so the easiest way is probably to just convert the string to `yyyyMMdd` first, e.g.

```
CONCAT(RIGHT(@dt, 4), LEFT(@dt, 4))
```

Then convert that to a date:

```
DECLARE @dt varchar(8)= '02022020';
SELECT CONVERT(DATE, CONCAT(RIGHT(@dt, 4), LEFT(@dt, 4)), 112)
```

Comment: You may use `CONCAT(RIGHT(@dt, 4), SUBSTR(@dt, 1, 2), SUBSTR(@dt, 3, 2))` for it to handle dates where month and day is different.

Answer (score 0):

Below is the SQL statements to handle all the formats.

```
MM/dd/yyyy
yyyy/MM/dd
yyyyMMdd
yyyy-MM-dd
MMddyyyy


  DECLARE @date varchar(10)= '2020-03-15';
    SELECT CASE
               WHEN @date IS NULL
               THEN NULL
               WHEN TRY_CONVERT(DATE, @date) IS NOT NULL
               THEN CAST(@date AS DATE) 
               WHEN TRY_CONVERT(DATE, @date) IS NULL
               THEN CONVERT(DATE, CONCAT(RIGHT(@date, 4), LEFT(@date, 4)), 112)
           END;
```

Answer (score -3):

Have you tried the following? SELECT FORMAT (yourdate, 'MM-dd-yy'). let me know

Comment: This will generate an error, as the OP's source value is a string data type.